# How to use key value to search in map in HQL query

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, hashmap, hql

In Java when having Object Book with fields price and name 
and `Map<Long, String>` with books objects I have trouble with where clause I want to make following query:

```
SELECT b FROM books
WHERE (b.price, b.name) IN ((20, 'book1'), (30, 'book2'), (15, 'book3'))
```

I couldn't find result, tried [HQL query for id pairs / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772032/hql-query-for-id-pairs-tuples) 
and [How to check if a pair exists using HQL in query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036036/how-to-check-if-a-pair-exists-using-hql-in-query)
and [JPA named query match a list of tuples in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832551/jpa-named-query-match-a-list-of-tuples-in-in-clause)

Comment: what is the problem in the 3rd option: JPA named query match a list of tuples in IN clause? I haven't tried but looks good. Can you please share the error you are getting while using the 3rd option?

Comment: 3rd option involves creating another entity, which I want to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most row value expression predicates are just syntax sugar for some more verbose syntax. In your case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books b
WHERE (b.price = 20 AND b.name = 'book1')
   OR (b.price = 30 AND b.name = 'book2')
   OR (b.price = 15 AND b.name = 'book3')
```

Note that if you want to build this kind of predicate dynamically, you have to either write a SQL builder yourself, mapping your map to the SQL string and bind variable set, or use an existing one like [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org)

If you have more complex syntaxes that you want to emulate this way, you can use the [jOOQ SQL translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/) to translate them from standard SQL to more basic SQL

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)